# What is the error when im trying to add image?

Tags: javascript

The output should be that every time that there is an opponent's player around the click, he becomes the player who is currently pressed. The code I sent is a check for the row above and chanching its image. The problem is that every time it comes to adding the image, it writes a red line underneath and nothing happens. What is the reason for this?

```
function Eating_Action(idClicked, rowClicked, colClicked) {

    
    IDRup = (rowClicked - 1) * BoardSize + colClicked;
    IDRdown = (rowClicked + 1) * BoardSize + colClicked
    IDCright = rowClicked * BoardSize + (colClicked + 1);
    IDCleft = Number(rowClicked) * Number(BoardSize) + (Number(colClicked) - 1);
    IDDleftdown = Number(First1Clicked) + Number(Number(BoardSize) - 1);
    IDDleftup = (rowClicked - 1) * BoardSize + (colClicked - 1);
    IDDrightdown = Number(First1Clicked) + Number(Number(BoardSize) + 1);
    IDDrightup = (First1Clicked) - (BoardSize - 1);

    //check all the pieces around the place that was clicked and change it to 

    if (intBoard[rowClicked][colClicked] == 1) {

        //check eating for UP ROW
        if (rowClicked - 1 >= 0) {
            if (intBoard[rowClicked - 1][colClicked] == 2) {
                document.getElementById(IDRup).innerHTML = "<img width='50px' height='50px' src='O.png'/>";
                intBoard[rowClicked - 1][colClicked] = 1;
            }
        }
```

Comment: It is not clear what is IDRup, is it a selector?

Comment: -"it writes a red line underneath"_ where do you see the red line, it's not obvious from what you've said.

Comment: it writes red line underneath the "<img width='50px' height='50px' src='O.png'/>"

Comment: IDRup is the ID of the above row